# OR operator inside EVALUATE statement COBOL

Tags: cobol

I would like to know if i can use the OR operator in this way:

```
EVALUATE TRUE
    WHEN (COD-USER NOT EQUAL TO 01) OR (COD-USER NOT EQUAL TO 02)
        ADD 1 TO CTN-ERROR

    WHEN 
    ...

END-EVALUATE
```

I think that it will work using IF but i need to do it with this statement. I have tried to put the parentheses on different positions but it did not work.

I have also tried to use different sentences like the following one and i got an invalid expression error:

```
COD-USER NOT EQUAL TO 01 OR 02
```

Comment: Instinctively, I'd say yes, but in that case, the best thing to do is a try. Make a mock-up small program, force the values of COD-USER to different levels, run it with displays, and see what happens.

Comment: @gazzz0x2z Well, i did what you said and it worked perfectly. The point is that the main program keeps giving me an error on the following line to the OR clause, right now i'm checking all the code inside the WHEN statement just to be sure the problem doesn't come from another part.

Comment: Well, you can use `OR` like that, but in that exact example it is pretty useless to do so. Consider three test cases. 01, 02 and 03. First rejected as it is not 02, second rejected as it is not 01, and third rejected as it is neither 01 nor 02. You'd need `AND` not OR. There's a couple of other ways.

Comment: You also have to indicate exactly what "did not work". Compile? Run? What, and what did happen.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question...

> I would like to know if i can use the OR operator in this way:

...is "yes."  However...

Is this what you want?

```
[...]
    05  WS-COD-USER PIC 99 VALUE ZEROES.
        88  DONT-ADD-1-TO-CTN-ERROR VALUES 1, 2.
[...]
    MOVE COD-USER TO WS-COD-USER
    EVALUATE TRUE
      WHEN DONT-ADD-1-TO-CTN-ERROR
           CONTINUE
      WHEN OTHER
           ADD 1 TO CTN-ERROR
    END-EVALUATE
```

This will not add 1 to `CTN-ERROR` if `COD-USER` is 1.  This will not add 1 to `CTN-ERROR` if `COD-USER` is 2.  If `COD-USER` is any other value 1 will be added to `CTN-ERROR`.

I'm presuming `COD-USER` is in an `FD` or copybook.  Otherwise you could just add the `88`-levels following it.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the ways. However, using the multiple WHENs with only one action, whilst entirely valid and correct, 1) is "unusual" to many programmers and 2) always looks like there has been a line or more accidentally deleted. I am not keen on EVALUATE other than TRUE (or FALSE, but see no real sense in using that) because it enforces the use of literals in the PROCEDURE DIVISION. Leading to the use of 88s as the second, and my preferred, way.

Comment: @BillWoodger 1) I was taking this as a "teachable moment" 2) In this case I would agree re literals in Procedure Division.  I was following the rule of least intrusion, perhaps inconsistently; it may be another teachable moment.  I am not an absolutist on 2, having seen 05  ONE PIC 9 VALUE 1 and 05 BLUE PIC X(5) VALUE 'BLUE'.

Comment: Yes, simple numbers which always mean the same thing (add 1 to x) should be literals. minimum-items-per-pallett should be descriptive. The BLUE is certainly pointless, but it should be a contextual name. By the by, ONE PIC 9 VALUE ZERO is fun when the coder says "it can't be looping, look, I add one to it" :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you will always `ADD 1 TO CTN-ERROR`

Not sure what you want your other `WHEN`'s to be or what you want to happen when `COD-USER` is 01 and when `COD-USER` is 02, but if you are wanting your code to something only when `COD-USER` is 01 or 02 then you could try something like:

```
EVALUATE COD-USER
    WHEN 01
        DO-SOMETHING
    WHEN 02
        DO-SOMETHING-ELSE
    WHEN OTHER
        ADD 1 TO CTN-ERROR
END-EVALUATE
```

OR

```
EVALUATE TRUE
    WHEN COD-USER = 01
        DO-SOMETHING
    WHEN COD-USER = 02
        DO-SOMETHING-ELSE
    WHEN OTHER
        ADD 1 TO CTN-ERROR
END-EVALUATE
```

This will do whatever you need it to when you match on 01 or 02 and anything else adds 1 to your count.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use OR but the way you have written code will always be true as someone already stated in above answer. When can be written twice also as shown below

```
EVALUATE TRUE
  WHEN COD-USER = 01
  WHEN COD-USER = 02
    CONTINUE
  WHEN OTHER
    ADD 1 TO CTN-ERROR
END-EVALUATE
```

In the above example when COD-USER = 01 or when COD-USER = 02 it will continue and for all other condition it will add 1 to the CTN-ERROR

Comment: This is the answer that @cschneid had originally, so see this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37002635/or-operator-inside-evaluate-statement-cobol#comment61574035_37008057

Comment: And whilst at it, have you also pondered the use of the leading zero?